# Windows 8 wired network adapter not connecting

Tags: networking, windows-8

After boot my computer's network status icon look like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/55lohkjpe0gyhsv/Untitled.png) and it said "Rastricted" on adapter. Button "Troubleshoot Problems" done nothing, Only temporarily fix are disabling and enabling adapter.

If not possible to fix it maybe i will be possible at startup do that what i do manually?

Comment: Did you manually set static DNS server? If so try to remove them go with auto DNS.

Comment: yes, they are set on the router, but that is not the problem. another computer works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved! Reinstall windows and problem solved the easy way.